# New Language pack not working properly

Tags: 2016, script, onedrive, language-pack

Installed a new Language pack in SP2016 server. Everything is working fine except one drive. One drive opens blank for the new language. On console I am getting below error:

> Script error for "odsp-next/pages/files/odb/ODBFiles.resx", needed by: odsp-next/pages/files/odb/FilesViewModel
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> Script error for "odsp-next/controls/commands/Commands.resx", needed by: odsp-next/actions/odb/OpenShortcutAction, odsp-next/controls/commandBarItem/CommandBarItemViewModel, odsp-next/utilities/selection/SelectionHelper, odsp-next/controls/leftNavExpander/commandSets/LeftNavExpanderCommandSet, odsp-next/providers/operation/MoveCopyItemsAsyncOperation, odsp-next/models/teachingBubble/TeachingBubbleCampaigns, odsp-next/controls/commands/BaseCommandSet, odsp-next/controls/newBadge/NewBadgeViewModel
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> Script error for "odsp-next/controls/loadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner.resx", needed by: odsp-next/controls/progressSpinnerFlat/ProgressSpinnerFlatViewModel, odsp-next/controls/loadingSpinner/LoadingSpinnerViewModel
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error was I had not installed Language dependent update after installing the language pack. Once I installed the update it started working properly.